# give yii bootstrap component a class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

How can I add an classes to this example:

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
    'type'=>'tabs', // 'tabs' or 'pills'
    'tabs'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Krant', 'content'=>'Home Content', 'active'=>true),
        array('label'=>'Postcode', 'content'=>'Postal'), 

    ),
));
?>
```

I can't find any kind of property that does this, is this intended to be so or just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Yii Conventions, you can try like this:

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
    'type'=>'tabs', // 'tabs' or 'pills'
    'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'yourClassName'),
    'tabs'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Krant', 'content'=>'Home Content', 'active'=>true, 'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'yourClassNameForThisChild')),
        array('label'=>'Postcode', 'content'=>'Postal'), 

    ),
));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do As like Following

```
<?php
  $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTabs', array(
    'type'=>'tabs', // 'tabs' or 'pills'
    'tabs'=>array(
       array('label'=>'Krant', 'content'=>'Home Content', 'active'=>true),
       array('label'=>'Postcode', 'content'=>'Postal'), 
     ),
     'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'class_name')
  ));
?>
```